# How to Connect Two Mysql database In PHP using Class

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using Object oriented Php. For connecting Two database in same host I am using code like this

```
<?php
class ConOs{
    var $dbhost1;
    var $dbuser1;
    var $dbpass1;
    var $dbhost2;
    var $dbuser2;
    var $dbpass2;

    function __construct() {

                            }
                            function connect(){
        $this->dbhost1="localhost";
        $this->dbuser1="user1";
        $this->dbpass1="db1";
        $this->dbhost2="localhost";
        $this->dbuser2="user2";
        $this->dbpass2="db2";

$conn1 = mysql_connect($this->dbhost1, $this->dbuser1, $this->dbpass1);
if(! $conn1 ){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("db1",$conn1);


$conn2 = mysql_connect($this->dbhost2, $this->dbuser2, $this->dbpass2, True);
if(! $conn2 ){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("db2", $conn2);


mysql_error();
                            }
}
?>
```

But $conn1 allways refused. Only $conn2 works. If I put $conn2 first, then only $conn1 works. How it possile to connect both database db1 & db2 ?

Comment: What errror do you get?

Comment: don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions

Comment: Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: And the fourth parameter at `$conn2` is only needed if you use `connect` again with the same parameters as in `$conn1`

Comment: @halojoy no error reports.. Only conncetion refused

Comment: @ArtOsi I don't know about mysqli.. Is it simple for understanding?

Comment: if you can work with `mysql_` you will be able to work with `mysqli_` just fine I think

Comment: **Warning**
This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

My dear stop to use mysql_* functions: use PDO :

```
class sujet{
private $id;

public function connect(){          
    try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev_bdd', 'root', '');
    }catch(Exception $e){
            die('Failed'. $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $bdd;            
}       
public function connect2(){         
    try {
            $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teamd2', 'root', '');
    }catch(Exception $e){
            die('Failed'. $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $bdd;            
}
public function __construct(){} 
public function recherche($search){
    $resultats = array();
    $req = $this->connect2()->prepare('SELECT * FROM sujets WHERE libelle like :search ');
    $req->execute(array(
        'search' => '%'.$search.'%',
         ));
    while($resultat = $req->fetch()){
        array_push($resultats,$resultat);
    }
    print_r($resultats);
    return $resultats;      
}
    private function queryMatiere(int $id){
    $requete = $this->connect()->query("SELECT libelle FROM matieres where id=$id");
    $data = $requete->fetch();
    return $data['libelle'];
}
}
```